# How did Cramer's work on permutations influence early pre-group theory (particularly the work of Lagrange and Vandermonde)?

Tags: biographical-details, abstract-algebra

In his *Réflexions* paper, Lagrange is using one of Cramer's results on the Elimination Theory for the proof of a [theorem](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/11527/was-it-common-for-lagrange-to-make-his-theorems-so-general-to-the-point-of-ambig). It seems that Cramer did some early work on the permutations of variables in connection to Elimination Theory. Is there a deeper connection between Lagrange's (and Vandermonde's) work on permutations and Cramer?

Comment: One place possibly worth looking is in the first volume of Thomas Muir's [**The Theory of Determinants in the Historical Order of Development**](https://archive.org/details/theoryofdetermin01muiruoft/page/n5/mode/2up).